Make cmake custom target depend on `install`?
How can I make a custom target depend on all or install?
I want to ensure that behave runs install before executing some tests:
# CMakeLists.txt
add_custom_target(behave
  behave
  WORKING_DIRECTORY ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}
  DEPENDS install
)

# I also tried without `DEPENDS` above and with this:
#add_dependencies(behave install)

But it seems to want to build a real target called install:
$ make behave
...
make[2]: *** No rule to make target 'CMakeFiles/install.dir/all', needed by 'CMakeFiles/behave.dir/all'.  Stop.
...


Install is install. You can invoke custom code during install with https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/install.html#script .
